# I have created a website with multiple pages that include HTML, PHP and javascript. Is there a way to upload all of these to WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, upload

I've created a website with about 15 pages and multiple css and jquery files. I've been asked to put the website onto WordPress. I already have a WordPress site attached to the correct URL but I'm really struggling to find the correct way to upload my files. I've watched many videos and tutorials but just can't get it to work.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I think this is beyond the scope of an answer here. I suggest to have a look at the wordpress documentation.

Comment: Surely the intention is to take the theme from your flat website and create a WP theme from it... then load the content in via the CMS? If you're just *uploading the files* you're not actually putting the website onto WordPress.

Comment: Yep, you have to do this manually. Read WP documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WordPress, design and content are separate, and design resides in the theme.

So start with developing a WordPress theme: read [Theme Development « WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development).

Once you have a theme in place, move the page content into the WordPress site, using the page and post functions.

Comment: I think I misunderstood what word press is. (Not fully customisable - not sure I like it). But, I'll attempt to develop my own theme and add content to pages like you said. Thanks for the help.